# ArcGIS for Android with Popup and Routing

Tags: java, android, routes, popup, arcgis

I want do develop an Android App with the SDK 'ArcGIS for Android'. There I have downloaded two Samples: PopupInWebMapForViewing an Routing. And thats my target: I want these two samples in one Projekt or in one .java-File.

I'm done this, but the App doesn't work on my Smartphone. It only shows up, that the App has stopped. If I comment out all the stuff from Routing, it will work. And if I uncomment all expect of the Layers from the Routing, it will also work. The Routing will be activate by long clicking on the map. But in this case, the App will crash.

I don't know much about java but its a projekt for the university. I hope that someone can help me.

Thank you all very much in advance for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Here's the code:

```
public class BAAppActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress dialog to show when route is being calculated
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    // Spatial references used for projecting points
    final SpatialReference wm = SpatialReference.create(102100);
    final SpatialReference egs = SpatialReference.create(4326);
    // Index of the currently selected route segment (-1 = no selection)
    int selectedSegmentID = -1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Lade die Basemap von ArcGIS online.
        map = new MapView(this, "map", "", "");
        setContentView(map);

        // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Add tiled layer to MapView
        tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
                "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(tileLayer);

        // Add the route graphic layer (shows the full route)
        routeLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        map.addLayer(routeLayer);

        // Add the hidden segments layer (for highlighting route segments)
        hiddenSegmentsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        map.addLayer(hiddenSegmentsLayer);

        // Make the segmentHider symbol "invisible"
        segmentHider.setAlpha(1);

        // Get the location service and start reading location. Don't auto-pan
        // to center our position
        LocationService ls = map.getLocationService();
        ls.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener());
        ls.start();
        ls.setAutoPan(false);

        // Set the directionsLabel with initial instructions.
        directionsLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.directionsLabel);
        directionsLabel.setText(getString(R.string.route_label));

        directionsLabel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (curDirections == null)
                    return;
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ShowDirections.class);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("directions", curDirections);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }

        });

        directionsLabel.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                routeLayer.removeAll();
                hiddenSegmentsLayer.removeAll();
                curRoute = null;
                curDirections = null;
                directionsLabel.setText(getString(R.string.route_label));
                return true;
            }

        });

        // Tippe auf die Karte und öffne ein Popup für das selektierte Feature.
        map.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
                // Get all the graphics within 20 pixels the click
                int[] indexes = hiddenSegmentsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 20);
                // Hide the currently selected segment
                hiddenSegmentsLayer.updateGraphic(selectedSegmentID,
                        segmentHider);

                if (indexes.length < 1) {
                    // If no segments were found but there is currently a route,
                    // zoom to the extent of the full route
                    if (curRoute != null) {
                        map.setExtent(curRoute.getEnvelope(), 250);
                        directionsLabel.setText(routeSummary);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                // Otherwise update our currently selected segment
                selectedSegmentID = indexes[0];
                Graphic selected = hiddenSegmentsLayer
                        .getGraphic(selectedSegmentID);
                // Highlight it on the map
                hiddenSegmentsLayer.updateGraphic(selectedSegmentID,
                        segmentShower);
                String direction = ((String) selected.getAttributeValue("text"));
                double time = ((Double) selected.getAttributeValue("time"))
                        .doubleValue();
                double length = ((Double) selected.getAttributeValue("length"))
                        .doubleValue();
                // Update the label with this direction's information
                String label = String.format(
                        "%s%nTime: %.1f minutes, Length: %.1f miles",
                        direction, time, length);
                directionsLabel.setText(label);
                // Zoom to the extent of that segment
                map.setExtent(selected.getGeometry(), 50);

                if (map.isLoaded()) {
                    // PopupContainer realisieren.
                    popupContainer = new PopupContainer(map);
                    int id = popupContainer.hashCode();
                    popupDialog = null;
                    // spinner (Auswahl) anzeigen.
                    if (progressDialog == null || !progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(map.getContext(), "", "Rufe Informationen ab...");

                    // Loop durch jeden Layer in der Basemap.
                    int tolerance = 20;
                        Envelope env = new Envelope(map.toMapPoint(x, y), 20 * map.getResolution(), 20 * map.getResolution());
                    Layer[] layers = map.getLayers();
                    count = new AtomicInteger();
                    for (Layer layer : layers) {
                        // Wenn der Layer noch nicht geladen wurde oder unsichtbar ist, nichts machen.
                        if (!layer.isInitialized() || !layer.isVisible())
                            continue;

                        if (layer instanceof ArcGISFeatureLayer) {
                            // Frage den FeatureLayer ab und zeige die Popups.
                            ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLayer = (ArcGISFeatureLayer) layer;
                            if (featureLayer.getPopupInfo() != null) {
                                // Frage den FeatureLayer ab, welcher mit den Popupdefinitionen verknüpft ist.
                                count.incrementAndGet();
                                new RunQueryFeatureLayerTask(x, y, tolerance, id).execute(featureLayer);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (layer instanceof ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {
                            // Frage den DynamicLayer ab und zeige die Popups.
                            ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer dynamicLayer = (ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) layer;
                            // Empfange Layerinfos für jeden Sub-Layer des dynamic map service layer.
                            ArcGISLayerInfo[] layerinfos = dynamicLayer.getAllLayers();
                            if (layerinfos == null)
                                continue;

                            // Loop durch jeden Sub-Layer.
                            for (ArcGISLayerInfo layerInfo : layerinfos) {
                                // erhalte PopupInfo für die Sub-Layer.
                                PopupInfo popupInfo = dynamicLayer.getPopupInfo(layerInfo.getId());
                                // Überspringe Sub-Layer, welche keine Popup-Definitionen enthalten.
                                if (popupInfo == null) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                // Überprüfe ob der Sub-Layer sichtbar ist.
                                ArcGISLayerInfo info = layerInfo;
                                while (info != null && info.isVisible()) {
                                    info = info.getParentLayer();
                                }
                                // Überspringe unsichtbare Sub-Layer.
                                if (info != null && ! info.isVisible()) {
                                    continue;
                                };

                                // Überprüfe ob der Sub-Layer innerhalb des Skalenbereichs ist.
                                double maxScale = (layerInfo.getMaxScale() != 0) ? layerInfo.getMaxScale():popupInfo.getMaxScale();
                                double minScale = (layerInfo.getMinScale() != 0) ? layerInfo.getMinScale():popupInfo.getMinScale();

                                if ((maxScale == 0 || map.getScale() > maxScale) && (minScale == 0 || map.getScale() < minScale)) {
                                    // Frage die Sub-Layer ab, welche mit den Popup-Definitionen verknüpft sind und sichtbar sind und im Skalenbereich liegen.
                                    count.incrementAndGet();
                                    new RunQueryDynamicLayerTask(env, layer, layerInfo.getId(), dynamicLayer.getSpatialReference(), id).execute(dynamicLayer.getUrl() + "/" + layerInfo.getId());
                                }
                            }
                        }               
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        map.setOnLongPressListener(new OnLongPressListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onLongPress(final float x, final float y) {

                // Clear the graphics and empty the directions list
                routeLayer.removeAll();
                hiddenSegmentsLayer.removeAll();
                curDirections = new ArrayList<String>();
                mResults = null;

                // retrieve the user clicked location
                final Point loc = map.toMapPoint(x, y);

                // Show that the route is calculating
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(BAAppActivity.this, "",
                        "Calculating route...", true);
                // Spawn the request off in a new thread to keep UI responsive
                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            // Start building up routing parameters
                            RoutingParameters rp = new RoutingParameters();
                            NAFeaturesAsFeature rfaf = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();
                            // Convert point to EGS (decimal degrees)
                            Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(loc, wm,
                                    egs);
                            // Create the stop points (start at our location, go
                            // to pressed location)
                            StopGraphic point1 = new StopGraphic(mLocation);
                            StopGraphic point2 = new StopGraphic(p);
                            rfaf.setFeatures(new Graphic[] { point1, point2 });
                            rfaf.setCompressedRequest(true);
                            rp.setStops(rfaf);
                            // Set the routing service output SR to our map
                            // service's SR
                            rp.setOutSpatialReference(wm);

                            // Create a new routing task pointing to an
                            // NAService (null credentials -> free service)
                            RoutingTask rt = new RoutingTask(
                                    "http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NetworkAnalysis/ESRI_Route_EU/NAServer/Route",
                                    null);

                            // Solve the route and use the results to update UI
                            // when received
                            mResults = rt.solve(rp);
                            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            mException = e;
                            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                        }
                    }
                };
                // Start the operation
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createPopupViews(Graphic[] graphics, final int id) {
        if (id != popupContainer.hashCode()) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            return;
        }

        if (popupDialog == null) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            // Mache einen Dialog für die popups und zeige ihn.
            popupDialog = new PopupDialog(map.getContext(), popupContainer);
            popupDialog.show();
        }
    }

    // Frage den Feature Layer durch einen Trefferüberprüfung ab.
    private class RunQueryFeatureLayerTask extends AsyncTask<ArcGISFeatureLayer, Void, Graphic[]> {

        private int tolerance;
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLayer;
        private int id;

        public RunQueryFeatureLayerTask(float x, float y, int tolerance, int id) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.tolerance = tolerance;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Graphic [] doInBackground(ArcGISFeatureLayer...params) {
            for (ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLayer : params) {
                this.featureLayer = featureLayer;
                // Grafik-IDs in der Nähe der Punkte abrufen.
                int[] ids = featureLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, tolerance);
                if (ids != null && ids.length > 0) {
                    ArrayList<Graphic> graphics = new ArrayList<Graphic>();
                    for (int id : ids) {
                        // Grafiken basierend auf den IDs erhalten.
                        Graphic g = featureLayer.getGraphic(id);
                        if (g == null)
                            continue;
                        graphics.add(g);
                    }
                    // Liefert ein Array von Grafiken in der Nähe des Punktes.
                    return graphics.toArray(new Graphic[0]);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Graphic[] graphics) {
            count.decrementAndGet();
            if (graphics == null || graphics.length == 0) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                return;
            }

            for (Graphic gr : graphics) {
                Popup popup = featureLayer.createPopup(map, 0, gr);
                popupContainer.addPopup(popup);
            }
            createPopupViews(graphics, id);
        }

    }

    // Frage den Dynamic Map Service Layer mit QueryTask ab.
    private class RunQueryDynamicLayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FeatureSet> {
        private Envelope env;
        private SpatialReference sr;
        private int id;
        private Layer layer;
        private int subLayerId;

        public RunQueryDynamicLayerTask(Envelope env, Layer layer, int subLayerId, SpatialReference sr, int id) {
            super();
            this.env = env;
            this.sr = sr;
            this.id = id;
            this.layer = layer;
            this.subLayerId = subLayerId;
        }

        @Override
        protected FeatureSet doInBackground(String... urls) {
            for (String url : urls) {
                // Erhalte Grafiken innerhalb der Hülle.
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setInSpatialReference(sr);
                query.setOutSpatialReference(sr);
                query.setGeometry(env);
                query.setMaxFeatures(10);
                query.setOutFields(new String[] { "*" });

                QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask(url);
                try {
                    FeatureSet results = queryTask.execute(query);
                    return results;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final FeatureSet result) {
            count.decrementAndGet();
            if (result == null) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                return;
            }
            Graphic[] graphics = result.getGraphics();
            if (graphics == null || graphics.length == 0) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                return;
            }
            // Überprüfen, ob die angeforderte PopupContainer-Id identisch mit dem aktuellen PopupContainer ist.
            // Andernfalls verlasse die veralteten Abfragen.
            if (id != popupContainer.hashCode()) {
                // Spinner verwerfen.
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                return;
            }
            PopupInfo popupInfo = layer.getPopupInfo(subLayerId);
            if (popupInfo == null) {
                // Spinner verwerfen.
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                return;
            }

            for (Graphic gr : graphics) {
                Popup popup = layer.createPopup(map,  subLayerId,  gr);
                popupContainer.addPopup(popup);

            }
            createPopupViews(graphics, id);

        }
    }

    // Ein angepasster Vollbild-Dialog.
    private class PopupDialog extends Dialog {
        private PopupContainer popupContainer;

        public PopupDialog(Context context, PopupContainer popupContainer) {
            super(context, android.R.style.Theme);
            this.popupContainer = popupContainer;           
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                layout.addView(popupContainer.getPopupContainerView(), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                setContentView(layout, params);
        }

    }

    void updateUI() {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (mResults == null) {
            Toast.makeText(BAAppActivity.this, mException.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        curRoute = mResults.getRoutes().get(0);
        // Symbols for the route and the destination (blue line, checker flag)
        SimpleLineSymbol routeSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.BLUE, 3);
        PictureMarkerSymbol destinationSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag_finish));

        // Add all the route segments with their relevant information to the
        // hiddenSegmentsLayer, and add the direction information to the list
        // of directions
        for (RoutingDirection rd : curRoute.getRoutingDirections()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> attribs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            attribs.put("text", rd.getText());
            attribs.put("time", Double.valueOf(rd.getTime()));
            attribs.put("length", Double.valueOf(rd.getLength()));
            curDirections.add(String.format(
                    "%s%nTime: %.1f minutes, Length: %.1f miles", rd.getText(),
                    rd.getTime(), rd.getLength()));
            hiddenSegmentsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(rd.getGeometry(),
                    segmentHider, attribs, null));
        }
        // Reset the selected segment
        selectedSegmentID = -1;

        // Add the full route graphic and destination graphic to the routeLayer
        Graphic routeGraphic = new Graphic(curRoute.getRoute().getGeometry(),
                routeSymbol);
        Graphic endGraphic = new Graphic(
                ((Polyline) routeGraphic.getGeometry()).getPoint(((Polyline) routeGraphic
                        .getGeometry()).getPointCount() - 1), destinationSymbol);
        routeLayer.addGraphics(new Graphic[] { routeGraphic, endGraphic });
        // Get the full route summary and set it as our current label
        routeSummary = String.format(
                "%s%nTotal time: %.1f minutes, length: %.1f miles",
                curRoute.getRouteName(), curRoute.getTotalTime(),
                curRoute.getTotalLength());
        directionsLabel.setText(routeSummary);
        // Zoom to the extent of the entire route with a padding
        map.setExtent(curRoute.getEnvelope(), 250);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Response from directions list view
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String direction = data.getStringExtra("returnedDirection");
                if (direction == null)
                    return;
                // Look for the graphic that corresponds to this direction
                for (int index : hiddenSegmentsLayer.getGraphicIDs()) {
                    Graphic g = hiddenSegmentsLayer.getGraphic(index);
                    if (direction
                            .contains((String) g.getAttributeValue("text"))) {
                        // When found, hide the currently selected, show the new
                        // selection
                        hiddenSegmentsLayer.updateGraphic(selectedSegmentID,
                                segmentHider);
                        hiddenSegmentsLayer.updateGraphic(index, segmentShower);
                        selectedSegmentID = index;
                        // Update label with information for that direction
                        directionsLabel.setText(direction);
                        // Zoom to the extent of that segment
                        map.setExtent(
                                hiddenSegmentsLayer.getGraphic(
                                        selectedSegmentID).getGeometry(), 50);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public MyLocationListener() {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * If location changes, update our current location. If being found for
         * the first time, zoom to our current position with a resolution of 20
         */
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc == null)
                return;
            boolean zoomToMe = (mLocation == null) ? true : false;
            mLocation = new Point(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());
            if (zoomToMe) {
                Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mLocation, egs, wm);
                map.zoomToResolution(p, 20.0);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

And LogCat:

```
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937): Can not parse MapView.initExtent from xml
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "-19332033.11," (at offset 9)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:545)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at com.esri.android.map.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at fhffm.wernicke.ba.app.BAAppActivity.onCreate(BAAppActivity.java:111)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
10-28 14:19:27.586: E/ArcGIS(26937):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 14:19:27.806: E/SensorManager(26937): thread start
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fhffm.wernicke.ba.app/fhffm.wernicke.ba.app.BAAppActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at fhffm.wernicke.ba.app.BAAppActivity.onCreate(BAAppActivity.java:146)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
10-28 14:19:27.816: E/AndroidRuntime(26937):    ... 11 more
```

Best regards
losaruka

Comment: This is really lot of code. Please debug your application and post only the problematic part.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I debug my Code?

Comment: Well.. do you use eclipse, netbeans or any other IDE?

Comment: I use Eclipse. If u mean LogCat: http://d-h.st/eJp

Comment: Could you update your question posting the logcat?

Comment: Yes, done. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In the Routing sample, look at res/layout/main.xml. The MapView is declared with this XML:

```
<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    initExtent = "-19332033.11, -3516.27, -1720941.80, 11737211.28">
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>
```

Unfortunately, the format of initExtent is incorrect. It should have spaces only, not commas:

```
    initExtent = "-19332033.11 -3516.27 -1720941.80 11737211.28">
```

Remove the commas and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, this problem already solved. But its also interessting, whats the right format.
But i got two new problems ;)

Comment: Maybe you should have started a new question, instead editing this question to basically delete the text of your original question--which would have been useful for others, and for which my answer is correct--with an entirely new question.

Comment: Yes your right. I'm sorry. I will look for the old code and make a new question :)

Comment: No worries. Rookie mistake. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself:

Delete this:

```
map = new MapView(this, "some map", "", "");
setContentView(map);
```

And add this:

```
featureLayer = new ArcGISFeatureLayer(
                "featureLayer", MODE.ONDEMAND);
map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

after:

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
                 "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
map.addLayer(tileLayer);
```

But I have a new Problem: If I want to tab on a Feature it searchs a long time and nothing come out. And if I tap on the routeoverview the app crashes. I think it crashes because of two "onSingleTab" methods. How can I make two of this for two different things (I tested 'Routing' with "onSingleTab1"...)? In this code are also the thing with the Features. I think it doesn't appear because the loop searches for layers. but the only layer i have is the featurelayer with features. I don't know...

```
map.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
                if (map.isLoaded()) {
                    // PopupContainer realisieren.
                    popupContainer = new PopupContainer(map);
                    int id = popupContainer.hashCode();
                    popupDialog = null;
                    // spinner (Auswahl) anzeigen.
                    if (progressDialog == null || !progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(map.getContext(), "", "Rufe Informationen ab...");

                    // Loop durch jeden Layer in der Basemap.
                    int tolerance = 20;
                        Envelope env = new Envelope(map.toMapPoint(x, y), 20 * map.getResolution(), 20 * map.getResolution());
                    Layer[] layers = map.getLayers();
                    count = new AtomicInteger();
                    for (Layer layer : layers) {
                        // Wenn der Layer noch nicht geladen wurde oder unsichtbar ist, nichts machen.
                        if (!layer.isInitialized() || !layer.isVisible())
                            continue;

                        if (layer instanceof ArcGISFeatureLayer) {
                            // Frage den FeatureLayer ab und zeige die Popups.
                            ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLayer = (ArcGISFeatureLayer) layer;
                            if (featureLayer.getPopupInfo() != null) {
                                // Frage den FeatureLayer ab, welcher mit den Popupdefinitionen verknüpft ist.
                                count.incrementAndGet();
                                new RunQueryFeatureLayerTask(x, y, tolerance, id).execute(featureLayer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ////////////////////////////// Routing /////////////////////////////
            public void onSingleTap1(float x, float y) {
            // Get all the graphics within 20 pixels the click
            int[] indexes = hiddenSegmentsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 20);
            // Hide the currently selected segment
            hiddenSegmentsLayer.updateGraphic(selectedSegmentID,
                    segmentHider);

            if (indexes.length < 1) {
                // If no segments were found but there is currently a route,
                // zoom to the extent of the full route
                if (curRoute != null) {
                    map.setExtent(curRoute.getEnvelope(), 250);
                    directionsLabel.setText(routeSummary);
                }
                return;
            }
            // Otherwise update our currently selected segment
            selectedSegmentID = indexes[0];
            Graphic selected = hiddenSegmentsLayer
                    .getGraphic(selectedSegmentID);
            // Highlight it on the map
            hiddenSegmentsLayer.updateGraphic(selectedSegmentID,
                    segmentShower);
            String direction = ((String) selected.getAttributeValue("text"));
            double time = ((Double) selected.getAttributeValue("time"))
                    .doubleValue();
            double length = ((Double) selected.getAttributeValue("length"))
                    .doubleValue();
            // Update the label with this direction's information
            String label = String.format(
                    "%s%nTime: %.1f minutes, Length: %.1f miles",
                    direction, time, length);
            directionsLabel.setText(label);
            // Zoom to the extent of that segment
            map.setExtent(selected.getGeometry(), 50);
            }
        });
```

Best regards

losaruka